# How to write elisp to auto-correct misspelt variables

Tags: emacs, elisp, autocorrect

Suppose I wrote

```
var longlongname = 1;
```

and I misspelled it as **linglongname**. How can I find a package or write a function to correct it?

(sometimes I'm lazy and prefer to trigger a key to fix previous misspelt word rather than move cursor around and correct it manually.)

Comment: For normal text documents there is `flyspell-mode`. I do not think that you will find anything appropriate for the declaration/definition of variable names in program texts. In program texts it is not clear whether the `ling` in `linglongname` has a special meaning. For variable references you could use `semantic-mode` with auto-completion.

Comment: Try library `completion.el`, which comes with Emacs. It is quite old, but still works well. It won't *correct* such mistakes once made, but (like other completion libraries) it can help *prevent* them. It lets you type a few chars and complete them (using `M-RET` or `C-RET`, by default) to terms already typed or already in the buffer or other buffers. Get in the habit of using it and you will have no problem with long identifiers that can trip up your fingers if typed char by char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a fun Elisp exercise.  Recipe for a function that does what you want:

- Build a dictionary of all words occurring in the buffer.
- Calculate the Levenshtein distance of all these words to the word in question.
- Replace the word in question with the most similar word according to the Levenshtein distance.

The Levenshtein distance is easy to compute.  It basically counts the number of changes you have to make to one word in order to transform it into another.  I'm sure someone has already implemented the Levenshtein distance in Elisp.  In a more advanced solution you could perhaps use the syntax table to narrow down the dictionary to tokens that actually are variables.  If there is more than one token with the minimal Levenshtein distance, you'd have to prompt the user before substituting.  If the Levenshtein distance of the closest match is above a certain threshold (e.g., Levenshtein distance / total number of characters in the two words > 1/5), you might not want to replace at all because the closest match is not close enough to be a plausible candidate.

Answer (score 1):

This problem that you want to solve is undecidable in the general case.

In particular cases, you can use flymake combined with flyspell.

Other packages that would be useful for yor in combination with flymake would be `company` and `auto-complete`.